# Where is the SampleZipfileProvider class?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

At the bottom of the section in Google's dev guide on expansion files (http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html#ZipLib) there is the following text.

> APEZProvider - Most applications don't need to use this class. This
>   class defines a ContentProvider that marshals the data from the ZIP
>   files through a content provider Uri in order to provide file access
>   for certain Android APIs that expect Uri access to media files. The
>   sample application available in the Apk Expansion package demonstrates
>   a scenario in which this class is useful to specify a video with
>   VideoView.setVideoURI(). See the sample app's class
>   SampleZipfileProvider for an example of how to extend this class to
>   use in your application.

The sample application in question doesn't contain this class. But it does contain a reference to a .SampleVideoPlayerActivity file in the AndroidManifest.xml, which is not present in the project either.

Has anyone tried to implement a concrete class based on the `APEZProvider` and used it with `VideoView.setVideoURI()`?

I have implemented the class:

```
public class ZipFileContentProvider extends APEZProvider {

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return "com.myCompany.myAppName.provider.ZipFileContentProvider";
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to use it with the `VideoView.setVideoURI()` call. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It turned out that my ZipFileContentProvider was sufficient. For those coming across this problem. Here is what I did to use the content provider for the VideoView.setVideoURI() method.

Add provider to Manifest.

```
<provider android:authorities="com.myCompany.myAppName.provider.ZipFileContentProvider" android:name=".ZipFileContentProvider"></provider>
```

In video player class:

```
final String AUTHORITY = "com.myCompany.myAppName.provider.ZipFileContentProvider";
final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY);
video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/" + videoFileName + ".mp4"));
```

Comment: I couldn't find the SampleZipfileProvider either. I have no idea how your answer works, but it does; thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add that if your files are in a folder inside the zip (like mine were), you'll need to include that in the path. For example Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/MyFolder/" + videoFileName + ".mp4")

Comment: You are my hero! Like Blundell, I don't know how it works, but it does and I'll take it :D
Thank you! +1

Comment: You can find the example here now: https://github.com/google/play-apk-expansion/blob/master/apkx_sample/src/com/example/google/play/apkx/SampleZipFileProvider.java

Comment: @elprl  can i set notification sound from expansion file through URI?