# getFileDescriptor returns null while reading mp3 files from the expansion files

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have downloaded and stored the expansion files successfully.But it crashes when i try to play the mp3 inside..

```
            ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(getApplicationContext(),
                    1, 0);

            InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream("mysong.mp3");
            AssetFileDescriptor asd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("mysong.mp3");
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(asd.getFileDescriptor(), asd.getStartOffset(), asd.getLength());
                    asd.close();
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Here the logcat says both the inputstream and the file descriptor are null..Can anyone help me ?

Comment: does this question solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051213/accessing-apk-expansion-file-with-uri-with-google-zip-expansion-library-causes ?

Answer (score 2):

Finaly it solved.. The file name should be with the full path..

```
AssetFileDescriptor asd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("main.1.com.mypackage.app/mysong.mp3");
```