# How to play video from apk expansion files?

Tags: android, eclipse

I create developing app in android which have about 500 mb video i use for uploading apk expansion files method i upload expansion and download it but now i cant play videos from it   http://blogmobile.itude.com/2012/11/22/expanding-your-horizons-using-expansion-files-for-android/  i follow this example for playing video but it's not working with me http://ktakeda47.blogspot.com/2012/04/apk-expansion-files.html i followed this link for expansion file downloading .Now plz help me how to play videos from expansion file Dir="/sdcard/Android/obb"  ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following code to play mp4 from obb `APKexpansion` file using `APKExpansionSupport` lib:

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = null;
AssetFileDescriptor mAFD= null;
try {
    expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(this, 1, 0);
    mAFD = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(strVideoFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    if (expansionFile==null || mAFD == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "obb is not here or doesn't contain file: "+strVideoFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mAFD.getFileDescriptor(), mAFD.getStartOffset(), mAFD.getLength());
```

Remember - you have to pack obb zip archive without any compression level. This is very important. It must be a zip archive with no compression (level=0).
[However there is a `URI` mentioned in APKES docs (speaking of `VideoView`)](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) but I cant get a glue how to get the `URI` from APKES. [Finally I found how to do it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623350/where-is-the-samplezipfileprovider-class)
So to use URI you has to extend `com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.APEZProvider` like in his example and make changes to Manifest and it should work.